# Design approach of ios status bar when implementing a side menu

Tags: ios, menu

I am first and foremost a programmer and struggle to make good designs, but with changes coming to ios I am at somewhat of a crossroads when it comes to how I might handle the status bar when implementing a side menu.

See below:

[image]

As you can see the status bar is sticking right on top. If I move the side menu down, it's just black and drowns the status bar information (i.e. carrier, wifi, etc). Even I change the status bar's color, I'm not sure moving down the menu flows well because then it is out of flush with the right side of the screen (unless I move it down as well).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not an iOS dev, but can't you hide the status bar?  I have plenty of apps that hide it, especially games.  It's still accessible if you pull the shade down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new iOS does a lot of work specifying depth -- so the first thing I'd look at is where each of the items -- the main screen, the status bar and the slide menu -- live on a plane.

The most common use of this menu pattern I've seen is Facebook's style, where the menu lives seemingly next to the content. Of course, Facebook treats the status bar as a fixed element, so this doesn't help your particular question much.

In my opinion, I'd have the menu live *above* the status bar and content layers. When it slides in, it would partially obscure the status bar and content (and, with the new APIs, give it a cool background blur!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the status bar as part of your view now and apply a background colour as needed in all views. Eg a purple background like you had in the top view controller.

If you could, have a visual designer review it to give you some advice.